# Supremum/minimum of union and intersection

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum

Determine infimum, supremum, maximum, minimum of the following

1. $(-2,2] \cup (3,8]$
   I would say the infimum is -2, no minimum, supremum=maximum=8 ?
2. $(\mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{Q}) \cap [–5,5]$
   So the intersection is the empty set, so there are no suprema/infimum?
3. $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (1+1/2^n, n+2)$ wouldn't the union be $(1, \infty)$? So supremum would be infinity and infimum would be 1 and no minimum and maximum?
4. $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-1/n^2, 2-1/n) $ would the intersection be 1? Then what could I say about supremum and infimum?

Edited the typo in 2)

Comment: (1) is correct.  (2)... you talk about "the intersection"... where do you see an intersection?  The set described in (2) is the set of all irrational reals unioned with the set of all reals from $-5$ to $5$ inclusive.  The set certainly isn't empty.  For (3) it depends on if you treat $0$ as a natural number or not.  Assuming you do, and assuming you allow extrema to *be* infinity then yes that is correct.

Comment: As for (4), note that for $n=1$ you have the interval is $(0,1)$ so $1$ is not included in the final result since it is not included in the first result.

Comment: @JMoravitzthank you so much, I had a typo in the second it should have been $\cap$ instead $\cup$ (therefor I talked about intersection); so this intersection would definitely be empty?

Comment: So as for (4), that means tge intersection woukd be empty?

Comment: No, it would be all the irrational numbers on the interval $[-5,5]$

Comment: @Pam1499 thank you! But how could I write the infimum/supremum in this case? Would it just be -5 and 5 and no maximum and minimum?

Comment: Well, the supremum would be 5 and the infimum would be -5...

Comment: Notice that every non degenerate interval on $\mathbb{R}$ contains both rational and irrational numbers